# UserControl instead of details GridView

Tags: winforms, devexpress-windows-ui

I need a big customization on how the standard details grid view in DevExpress `XtraGrid` is displayed.

What I need to achieve is when user expands the 'master' row, I need to display details view which should also contain some additional controls outside the grid like buttons etc.

So basically, when user expands the 'master' row, I need to show my own `UserControl`, which would include the details `GridView` itself and also my buttons etc.

Anybody tried to accomplish similar functionality?
Any hints where should I start?

Comment: Have you considered extending [ColumnView](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.class) class?

Comment: Hi, I had to start from BaseView, and create a lot of custom stuff. Example to follow: https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-place-any-control-to-the-detail-view-e3387